Is emptying the Recycle Bin slow on purpose?
Why is it that, upon trying to delete multiple GB of files from my Recycle Bin, it's extremely slow and always 'discovering files' but, upon using a command such as the del command below, it's instantaneous?
del /f C:\$Recycle.Bin\[some id]

I haven't seen a single post online (from what I've searched) talking about this, which I find interesting. I did find a post on StackOverflow that provided the rd command mentioned below, however the context was different.)
Is this done on purpose by Microsoft? If so, why?
Note: As to why I used del; I tried to use this:
rd /s %systemdrive%\$Recycle.bin

However it seems to take longer than using del.

my guess is the del command is returning before its completed its work (async), whereas the gui is synchronous, and stays open until the task is done. just a guess. have you compared the time to send content to the recyclebin with delete, vs permenantly deleting it with Shift + Del ? I'm wondering if that might help demonstrate the differences between the two methods.

In addition to what @FrankThomas said: the GUI will take something else in mind. The recycle bin spans multiple drives and will delete everything from all places. It has multiple databases, and that makes it that the GUI takes longer. Also, the recycle bin can be used by multiple users, so it doesn't want to delete everything. So instead, it deletes file by file. That is slower, but ensures only the files for your user are deleted.

@FrankThomas I'll probably make a tool to quickly download random high-res images from wherever so I can fill up folders with big files quickly, and then try out Permanent Deletion.

As mentioned in the comments, The recycle bin is a complicated beast.  It spans multiple volumes and users and can potentially contain a CRAPTON(tm) of files to sort through.  Keep in mind too that it can handle multiple versions of the same file being deleted and recover whichever of those you want.
The recycle bin is a feature of the windows shell and I think that it isn't logical to compare delete operations that don't preserve things via command line to one that does via GUI shell.
With that said.. they did seem to do SOMETHING a long time ago that seemed to make it exponentially slower.  That is just my opinion.
Del

Deletes one or more files.

The del operation simply does a windows FindFirstFile() FindNextFile() and climbs up the directory tree deleting files (and only files) as it goes.
Rd

Removes all directories and files in the specified directory in addition to the directory itself.

The rd operation has to first recurse to the top of the tree, then start walking backward down the tree deleting files.  Each time it deletes the last file in a directory (also a file), it deletes the directory itself and goes up one more level.
